# creating worksheets from column in worksheet and using another worksheet as a template

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

here's the code:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Company").Range("B2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet   
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

This creates new worksheets based on my column now I have a second piece that I need to use to as a "template" i.e. it has header info and a button.

```
Sub Wsh_PasteSpecial()
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

Rem Set working worksheets
Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RecordsTemplate") '<-- my template

Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target") '<-- QUESTION IS HOW DO I SET THE TARGET.

    WshSrc.Cells.Copy
    With WshTrg.Cells
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that how would set the target? Are you getting an error? Is it not doing what you want it to do? What's the problem/question here?

Comment: Is it that "Target" isn't the name of the sheet, but rather the name of the sheet is dynamically added in the top subroutine as `MyCell.Value`? CAn you just take all of the code in the bottom subroutine and paste it inside that For Loop in the top routine and set `SET WshTrg = Sheets(Sheets.Count)`?  I'm totally guessing here since it's not clear what are you trying to do and what problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged your two codes:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Company").Range("B2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RecordsTemplate") '<-- my template

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet   
        Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MyCell.Value)  
        WshSrc.Cells.Copy
        With WshTrg.Cells
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With      
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for the slow response, this worked great but I have a button that clears the spreadsheet, how can I get that to copy?

Comment: A button is something entirely different. Would be best to start a new question for it.